# How to adapt remote computer's resolution when connecting with RDP?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

When I'm using RDP in my home network, the resolution of the remote computer would adapt to the resolution of the connecting PC. This way, I can connect from my small laptop to my big screen desktop PC, and the desktop's resolution is changed from `1920x1080` to `1024x800`.

Note that I'm not talking about **scaling down**, I'm talking about **true resolution change**, so that all open windows are changed in size.

At the office of one of my clients, they're always using Remote Desktop, but the behavior there is different: If the remote desktop's resolution is higher than that of the connecting laptop, **RDP is just showing scroll bars**. This is much much less convenient, since you have to scroll around all the time.

I cannot see any setting that's different at my client, than it is in my home network.

**How can RDP be configured so that it changes the remote desktop's resolution automatically?**

Answer (score 1):

If you run `mstsc.exe` there's a pannel `Display`, there is a slider which sets resolution for your RDP session. You may slide it to `Full Screen`, that way it'll adapt to your resolution.

[image]

Other possible options [here](https://superuser.com/a/618417/166160) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/138140/change-the-default-resolution-of-remote-desktop-connection-mstsc).